# How to find occurrences of list of letters efficiently with NLTK in Python?

Tags: python, nltk

I can read text corpuses with NLTK python2.6:

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
for fileid in gutenberg.fileids():
    num_chars = len(gutenberg.raw(fileid)) 
    num_words = len(gutenberg.words(fileid))
    num_sents = len(gutenberg.sents(fileid))
    num_vocab = len(set([w.lower() for w in gutenberg.words(fileid)]))
    print int(num_chars/num_words), int(num_words/num_sents), int(num_words/num_vocab), fileid
```

Now I'd like to find average occurences of letters by words and sentences, something like num_letters(whole_text, ['a', 'bb', 'ccc']). Expected output is:

a = n11/n12, bb = n21/n22, ccc = n31/n32

where n11 = occurrences in words and n12 = occurrences on sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by finding all the matches for each element you want to match against in the bulk of the text using regular expressions:

```
import re
matches = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'and']

#add this line into your for loop:
    num_letter_dict = dict([(match, len([seq.start() for seq in 
            re.finditer(match, gutenberg.raw(fileid))])) for match in matches])
```

This creates a dictionary of all matches and their frequency. So for the first text, `austen-emma.txt`, we get for `num_letter_dict`:

```
{'a': 53669, 'and': 5257, 'ccc': 0, 'bb': 52}
```

To go from here to average number of occurrences in words and sentences is straight forward, just divide through by `num_words` and `num_sents`, respectively.

To find the number of words that include these elements (repetitions within a word are not counted), use:

```
num_letter_in_words = dict([(match, len([word for word in gutenberg.words(fileid)
                                      if match in word])) for match in matches])
#from the same text gives:
{'a': 50043, 'and': 5257, 'ccc': 0, 'bb': 52}
```

As an example:

```
text = 'apples pairs bannanas'
matches = ['a', 'n', 'p']
#gives:
{'a': 3, 'p': 2, 'n': 1}
```

Comment: How would you get a percentage of occurrence of letter used per words? Now it seems to count "a" several times per word, I'm I right?

Comment: @PHPGAE - I'm sorry, I don't understand your question, could you give more detail. And do you actually mean letters (a,b,c,d,e...)?

Comment: Say word "household" has 2*h, 2*o, 2*ho,... If I want to get average occurrence of the strings [h, o, ho] per words I think I need to count them only once per word, not twice. Its different compared to get average count per whole text corpus.

Comment: @PHPGAE - oh, do you mean average occurrence per word that the element appears in (ie. excluding all words that it doesn't appear in..)?

Comment: @PHPGAE - I'm not sure I follow, I think you should add clear examples of what you want as output for a sample subtext and letters. Or even accept this answer (as I've answered your question as posted), and ask another question. :)

Comment: num_words = len(gutenberg.words(fileid)) gives all words from corpus, some of them has element, some has several times, some doesn't have at all. Now this is a little bit beyond original question, but I think its important extension for my research. In how many words element exists and what is the average of that to all words available.

Comment: It may have been incorrectly or incompletely asked, but this is what is stated "to find average occurences of letters by words". Your code gives number of occurrences, but doesn't solve the latter part of the question. Sure its helpful already.